# Updating OneNote from VBA Excel

Tags: excel, office-interop, onenote, vba

I'm trying to automate the addition of a link to a report in OneNote. Basically, I have a already running macro producing a daily report in VBA Excel and saving a values only copy in a given folder. I would now like to add to the code so that an hyperlink is created in OneNote so the end-user may access the values-only file by cliking on that hyperlink.

I've found a piece of VBA code that creates a new page in a Notebook on Microsoft webpage: [Create New Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377183%28v=office.14%29)

I have modified the code so that it'll go to the Notebook, Section and then Page I tell it to. Then I can have VBA it fetch back the PageContent through XML format.

Now here's the thing: I have a table for the month that starts only with one line two columns ie. the headers (report date and link). Now everyday, I wish to add a line to that table before writing the day's date and the link.

How would I do that in OneNote with VBA Excel ? Is it possible ? Or would I need to change to VB or C# to be able to use Office-InterOp to do so??

If I manage to create an extra line, I think I'd have no problem finding the two empty cells and writing the date and an hyperlink.

Can someone please help?

thanks
Sebastien

Answer (score -1):

After you get the page content in XML format, you just need to modify it to include the Table (or add new rows/cells to it and then call UpdatePageContent. Here is a sample page XML that has a simple Table:

```
<one:Page xmlns:one="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2010/onenote">
  <one:Outline>
    <one:OEChildren>
      <one:OE>
        <one:Table>
          <one:Row>
            <one:Cell>
              <one:OEChildren>
                <one:OE><one:T><![CDATA[Cell1]]></one:T></one:OE>
              </one:OEChildren>
            </one:Cell>
            <one:Cell>
              <one:OEChildren>
                <one:OE><one:T><![CDATA[Cell2]]></one:T></one:OE>
              </one:OEChildren>
            </one:Cell>
          </one:Row>
          <one:Row>
            <one:Cell>
              <one:OEChildren>
                <one:OE><one:T><![CDATA[Cell3]]></one:T></one:OE>
              </one:OEChildren>
            </one:Cell>
            <one:Cell>
              <one:OEChildren>
                <one:OE><one:T><![CDATA[Cell4]]></one:T></one:OE>
              </one:OEChildren>
            </one:Cell>
          </one:Row>
        </one:Table>
      </one:OE>
    </one:OEChildren>
  </one:Outline>
</one:Page>
```

Comment: where is the solution?!? This is just an XML snippet